# Save files added to web site

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to make a drag and drop function for a web page, and getting the file to be accessible in the code but i don't know how to save the uploaded
file to a folder on the server hosting.

EDIT:
I am hosting a plex server on the machine and want to be able to drag and drop files to save it in the folder where plex streams from.

Here is the code for the drop event handler:

```
function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        // If dropped items aren't files, reject them
        var dt = ev.dataTransfer;
        if (dt.items) {
          // Use DataTransferItemList interface to access the file(s)
          for (var i=0; i < dt.items.length; i++) {
            if (dt.items[i].kind == "file") {
              var f = dt.items[i].getAsFile();                  
            }
          }
         }
        }
```

Comment: What type of environment is your server running? Storing files to a directory on a server (as opposed to a database) is different between a .NET and a PHP environment - and so is retrieving the documents you drop. This is partly a JS issue, and partly a backend issue.

Comment: I am running an apache2 server on a ubuntu machine.

Comment: For a similar task I used [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). Open source, drag&drop, progress status, ready examples to manage the uploads with different backends

Comment: There is code which executes on server and there is code which executes on the client side. The code which executes on client side cannot by itself store files on the server. So, just a javascript in html is not enough. You need some server-side scripting, which can be in php, .net, java, python, even javascript... (all of that can be on apache...)